# How to get Admin name and password from Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to get the admin and its password, what i want to do, is authentificate everything with its credentials.

How to do it instead of hardcoding it by:

```
user = authenticate(username='me', password='12345')
login(request, user)
```

Comment: I don't understand...explain yourself better pls

Comment: the application is a simple tutorial, and the user dont need a login page, but it needs to save what he did to database, so it needs a `session` so, since he already created the admin user, i want to use the admin information to log him directly

Comment: Django a have a native session system, it uses cookie and allow anonymous users.

Comment: It is automatic if you enable the great middlewares (active by default). An example of usage is the message framework, it stores messages and send it only to the appropriate user. :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/ .

Comment: He doesnt need a login but he can create an admin...need to elaborate more if you want useful information from this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get password from database, it's only an hashed fingerprint. [Django password documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/)

Comment: yes, it is set in `pbkdf2` , so only the `anonymous user` is the solution